# Seeking explanation on renderPlot in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a trivial question after playing with this code

```
library(gapminder)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxInput("fit", "Add line of best fit", FALSE),
      selectInput("continents", "Continents",
                  choices = levels(gapminder$continent),
                  multiple = TRUE,
                  selected = 'Europe')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    data <- subset(gapminder,
                   continent %in% input$continents)
    
    p <- ggplot(data, aes(gdpPercap, lifeExp)) +
      geom_point() +
      scale_x_log10() 
    
    if (input$fit) {
      p <- p + geom_smooth(method = "lm") 
    }
    p 
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If I change part of the code above to this

```
  if (input$fit) {
      p + geom_smooth(method = "lm")       
     }
# p 
  })
}
```

The plot won't be displayed. Why do we have to be too verbose, that is, passing `p + geom_smooth()` to `p`, then calling `p` for it to work? Why can't we be more succinct by simply calling `p + geom_smooth()`? Is it because the code is wrapped inside `renderPlot()`?

Thankyou.

Comment: Could you pls add a small example dataframe to your code? Otherwise your code cannot execute and it's harder to follow you
Also, as a first try, add `return()` to your last line in the if statement

Comment: Hi @ThomasFuchs, I edited the OP to load the `gapminder` dataset. I tried `if (input$fit) { p + geom_smooth(method = "lm") return() }` as per your suggestion but the plot wasn't displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your if statement, the plot is returned and then rendered in case `input$fit` is TRUE. If `input$fit` is FALSE, the if statement returns NULL and therefore no plot is rendered. This is the default behaviour of `if()` in R.

You can solve your problem by simply add `else p` to your if statement like

```r
if (input$fit) p + geom_smooth(method = "lm") else p
```

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation, Thomas. This indicates that the example code was not well written. The `if...else...` makes it much easier to understand.

Comment: All good, working with curly brackets yield the same result. It's more that I try to avoid them for small if and if else statements, bit clearer